# Removing a MovieClip from Main Timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How do you remove a MovieClip from the main timeline in flash cs6? After the MovieClip plays, it just continues to loop for the duration of the Main Timeline. How can I end a MovieClip and also remove it from the Main Timeline once it is done playing?

Answer (score 0):

To `remove` a `display object` from your Main Timeline, you have to use `removeChild` method:

```
removeChild(myMovieClip);
```